# ASP webcontrols won't show me new values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a asp project (with C#) and i have need of a way to update files from a map (with files). I've created a asp:Content block with the following form:

```
<form id="editForm" runat="server">

        <table class="table table-hover">

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><h4><asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Text="title"/></h4></td>
              <td><asp:Textbox id="pageName" runat="server"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><h4><asp:Label id="Label3" runat="server" Text="pageurl"/></h4></td>
              <td><asp:Textbox id="pageURL" runat="server"/></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
                <div id="ckeditor_div" runat="server">>
            <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" runat="server">
            </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
               </div>
     <asp:Button ID="editButton" OnClick="Save" Text="save" runat="server"/>
     <br>
    <br>
    <asp:Label id="resultLabel" runat="server" />
   </form>
```

This asp:Content block also has a Page_Load method and a Save method.

```
        void Page_Load(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["title"]))
                {
                    string url = Request.QueryString["title"];
                    string[] htmlFile = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), url).Select(path => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path)).ToArray();

                    //if file exists
                    if (htmlFile.Length > 0)
                    {
                        //get file contents
                        string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/") + url);

                        //get's title
                        int tFirst = contents.IndexOf("<title>") + "<title>".Length;
                        int tLast = contents.LastIndexOf("</title>");
                        String nameResult = contents.Substring(tFirst, tLast - tFirst);

                        //get's editable code
                        int cFirst = contents.IndexOf("<div id='content'>") + "<div id='content'>".Length;
                        int cLast = contents.LastIndexOf("</div>");
                        String codeResult = contents.Substring(cFirst, cLast - cFirst);

                        //give CKEditor editable code to edit
                        CKEditor1.Text = codeResult;


                        //show page url
                        string sub = url.Substring(0, url.Length - 5);
                        pageURL.Text = sub;
                        pageName.Text = nameResult;
                    }


                }

            }
        }

void Save(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string newTitle = pageName.Text;
            string newURL = pageURL.Text;

            string editedURL = newURL.Replace(" ", "-");
            string newCode = CKEditor1.Text;

        }
```

When i run the page, the form get's filled with the info from the selected file. This works. After i change some values and press Save, the old, original values (the ones inserted into the .Texts on load) are returned. how can i get the new, edited values? Am i doing something wrong?

Edit: Nevermind folks. Forgot the if(!IsPostBack) loop. Now if you will excuse me i'm gonna shrivel up and cry now.

Comment: You haven't shown us the whole Page_Load. I doubt you're checking for `IsPostBack`.

Comment: yes, that seems to be it. I added a if(!IsPostBack) to the pageLoad(that was my complete pageload btw) and it worked. Dang. Sorry folks.